# can't use conda after I install anaconda on MAC

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, installation, conda

I install anaconda on my MAC, my system is 10.14.6, and following the instruction of 64-bit graphical installer, then I can't launch jupyter notebook from terminal, and conda is not found too, 
I find I cannot find python3 either, but I try to use brew install python3 to install python, it told me python3 has already on be installed, but I cannot find it.

[image]

Comment: What does `python3 --version` give?

Comment: Conda doesn't play well with other Python interpreters on the PATH. Make sure you don't have other Python installations on PATH or PYTHONPATH. You might need to remove the homebrew ones.